# Created Trait in Laravel Form Request File Can't be Called in another class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I just created PHP Trait inside Laravel Form Request file, alongside with Laravel Form Request class. The purpose of this is so i can use the trait inside laravel livewire component class. But somehow it throws an error

> **Trait "App\Http\Requests\Auth\LoginTrait" not found**

Is it related to laravel psr autoloading or what?

My LoginRequest.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests\Auth;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class LoginRequest extends FormRequest
{
    use LoginTrait;
}

trait LoginTrait
{

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function rules($data = null)
    {
        $phoneRule = getPhoneRule();
        $rule = isEmail($this->phone_email) ? 'email:rfc,dns' : "phone:$phoneRule," . 
                getCountryCode();
        return [
            'phone_email' => "required|$rule",
            'password' => 'required|min:6'
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get custom attributes for validator errors.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function attributes($data = null)
    {
        $attributes = [
            'phone_email' => 'Email/Whatsapp'
        ];
        if (isEmail($this->phone_email)) {
            $attributes['phone_email'] = 'Email';
        } else if (isPhoneNumber($this->phone_email)) {
            $attributes['phone_email'] = 'Whatsapp';
        }
        return $attributes;
    }
}
```

My LoginForm livewire component class:

```
<?php

namespace App\View\Components\Livewire\Forms;

use App\Http\Requests\Auth\LoginTrait;
use Livewire\Component;

class LoginForm extends Component
{
    use LoginTrait;
    public $phone_email;
    public $password;

    protected $validationAttributes;
    // protected $validationAttributes;
    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.livewire.forms.login-form');
    }

    public function updated($propertyName)
    {
        $this->validationAttributes = $this->attributes();
        $this->validateOnly($propertyName);
    }

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->fill([
            'phone_email' => old('phone_email')
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer for my problem, why can't we declare Class and Trait in same file (laravel)?

Comment: Yes, it's related to PSR namespaces. Laravel expects the namespace and classname to be the same as the file path/name

Comment: @aynber its is composer that expects it like that not Laravel

Comment: @lagbox It's both. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/contributions#coding-style

Comment: Why are you putting a trait _underneath_ a class??? Use a separate file

Answer (score -1):

Could your issue perhaps be related to LiveWire not working with Laravel's FormRequest, as described [here](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/input-validation) ?

Comment: I do aware that laravel livewire is not recomended using laravel form request best practice. So i just mix both of them only to get real time validation. Basically i just need certain methods like attributes and rules to show the errors. Form submission still handled by the controller with form request